# JavaScript (PWA) - What is the correct way to initialize service-worker?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

What is the better way to initialize service-worker used for PWA caching?

Method 1:
I expect that in this case will be installed new SW instance. I guess that's not necessary and I want to re-activate existing SW already running in the browser - am I right?

```js
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js').then(registration => {
      // Registration success
    }, function(err) {
      // Registration failed
    });
  });
}
```

Method 2: In this case I'm checking that there SW already registered and I'm installing registering a new one only if there is non registered.

```js
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(registrations => {
      const isServiceWorkerNotRegistered = registrations.length === 0;

      if (isServiceWorkerNotRegistered) {
          navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js').then(registration => {
              // Registration success
          }).catch(error => {
              // Registration failed
          });
      } else {
          console.log('Service worker already registered.');
      }
    });
  });
}
```

On top of that... Is it really necessary to wait for window to load (line 2)? Since SW is running asynchronously in the browser I guess I don't need the app to be completely loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Waiting for the `load` event is so that assets being downloaded by the service worker don't take bandwidth and device resources from rendering the currently requested page. See [improving the boilerplate](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/registration#improving_the_boilerplate).

For your registration question, use the simple first version.

> Unless you change the URL of the service worker script, navigator.serviceWorker.register() is effectively a no-op during subsequent visits.
>
> [*subsequent visits*](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/registration#subsequent_visits)

If the service worker is not registered, `register` will register it. If a service worker is already registered, `register` will basically not do anything.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. How can I use this load function with React?